# Where can I find the commentaries on Bhakti-rasamrta-sindhu of Rupa Gosvami?

Tags: gaudiya-vaishnavism

There are three commentaries on the Bhakti-rasāmṛta-sindhu of Śrī Rūpa Gosvāmī. They are by Śrī Jīva Gosvāmī, Śrī Mukunda dāsa and Śrī Viśvanātha Cakravartī Ṭhākura. Are the original sanskrit commentaries available somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can find them here:

1. https://archive.org/details/BRSHaribolKutir (Haridas das babaji edition)
2. https://archive.org/details/p_BRS (has only Viśvanātha Cakravartī's commentary)
3. http://scsmath.org/publications/pdfs-IndianLanguage/SriBhakti-rasamrita-sindhu.pdf (has only Jīva Gosvāmī's Commentary)
4. https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.353593/page/n37
5. https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.17903/page/n37
6. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7JhzNLs-FQEa0hsa2RpYmtwajg/view
7. https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.289713 (Ramanaryana Vidyaratna edition)
8. https://archive.org/details/HariBhaktiRasamritaSindhuNo6AchyutGranthaMala/mode/2up